# Record script using JMeter proxy from command line

Tags: manual-testing, jmeter, performance, load-testing

I have one requirement:

> I need to execute a command in command prompt that should trigger “Start” button of “HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder”. Even if I don't press “Start” button, the HTTP response should get recorded in non GUI mode.

I did trail and errors for several hours but that didn't workout for me.

Could anyone please help me out in solving this?

Comment: Not sure if Jmeter has such a feature as of now. You can use the Blazemeter browser plugin to record scripts.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to do the non-GUI recording with JMeter in command-line mode. I would suggest using another tool like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to capture the traffic and use service to make a JMX out of it.
[check here about Blazemeter.](https://converter.blazemeter.com)